# Notebook for Linux/Ubuntu commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome

Jupyter notebooks are a way of running code interactively while also providing note-taking functionality. While Jupyter supports the Python programming language by default, there are several different kernels available for other languages, like Java for example. I want to create a  Jupyter notebook for running linux terminal commands. If I would use jupyter notebook, I shall be using

> `!pwd`

What is the best way to do this? Are there other applications designed for this use case that are more effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (that you want to use Jupyter for bash, not write your own notebook software in/for bash), the Jupyter wiki has a section outlining the [kernels](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels) you can use, including one for [bash](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel).